# Is there any constraints when using joins on a cube dataset in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-dataset

I'm trying to join a cube dataset with cross Dataset as show below using right outer on two columns , But I am not able to solve the issue conflict joins.

I have tried changing the joins but couldn't solve it.

```
val data =Seq(("Data2","DATA1",3152)).toDF("column1","column2","value1");
+-------+-------+------+
|column1|column2|value1|
+-------+-------+------+
|  Data2|  DATA1|  3152|
+-------+-------+------+

val cubeDS= data.cube("column1","column2").agg(sum("value1"));
+-------+-------+-----------+
|column1|column2|sum(value1)|
+-------+-------+-----------+
|  Data2|  DATA1|       3152|
|   null|   null|       3152|
|   null|  DATA1|       3152|
|  Data2|   null|       3152|
+-------+-------+-----------+

val side =cubeDS.select("column1").distinct().limit(1);
+-------+
|column1|
+-------+
|   null|
+-------+

val top =cubeDS.select("column2").distinct().limit(1);
+-------+
|column2|
+-------+
|   null|
+-------+

val cross=side.crossJoin(top);
+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|
+-------+-------+
|   null|   null|
+-------+-------+
```

expected Result;

```
+-------+-------+-----------+
|column1|column2|sum(value1)|
+-------+-------+-----------+
|   null|   null|       3152|
+-------+-------+-----------+
```